# When referring to oneself using pronouns only, would it be appropriate to use "me" instead of "myself"?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

When you refer to yourself without saying your name, (without gendered pronouns) would it be of appropriate use to say "me" instead of "myself"?

for example:

> I would give me a big hug.

To give a better understanding of what I'm asking , I'm not saying I would hug myself, I’m saying I (one person) would hug me. (different person, but still referring to me) Like if `I` was <user472480> and `me` was <user472480 but from the past>

Sorry in advance if you couldn't understand my question. I tried my hardest to make it clear *enough* to answer, but I know it's still a weird question.

Comment: If you are talking about time travel where you go back in time and hug your previous incarnation, then I suppose you are entitled to use "me".  When we finally invent time travel, I'm sure that language will have to evolve in order to accommodate it. Meanwhile, in a fictional story - do what you want.

Comment: Can hardly answer without more context or examples. You have something in mind I think. Please tell us more.

Comment: You'd like to give "past you" a hug?

Comment: It's common to talk about "my younger self" or "me as a 20 year old" or things like that; using "me" without qualification looks a bit weird but depends on context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is fine; there’s really no other way to do it. This is a subjunctive sense for counterfactual conditions — you are not you! Insert *if I were you* to better understand, and compare these:

> *If I were you, I would hug me.* [Hug me.]
>
> *If I were you, I would hug myself.* [Hug yourself.]

Here are a few examples from the  [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org):

> *What would you do? I would give me the keys so I’d go upstairs, set the stairs on fire . . .*
>
> *How would you proceed, Dr Dorian? I would give me that news in private, no matter how angry I was at me.*
>
> *I mean, if I were you, I would fire me. I mean, you know how long it took me to do my work today?*